# Reduce verbosity of stringstream operations necessary to pass parameters to a function

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

Given the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

int main() {
  std::string str = "1 2";
  std::stringstream ss(str);

  int a, b;
  ss >> a;
  ss >> b;
  printf("Result: %d\n", add(a, b));
}
```

I'm wondering if there's any way to be less verbose about the part here:

```
int a, b;
ss >> a;
ss >> b;
printf("Result: %d\n", add(a, b));
```

And reduce the call to add into something like:

```
add(ss >> ?, ss >> ?) // ? because I don't know what'd you'd put there.
```

Basically, turning it into a one-liner.

Comment: `ss >> a >> b;` Please note that even if you make a function as you wish, the order of parameter evaluation is unspecified. (Sure, it is not a problem for sum :) )

Comment: @AlexD good to know...seems like there's no way to avoid declaring the variables like I had hoped...I didn't think there was, but I hoped it was just due to inexperience.

Comment: You still can make a function `int getInt(stringstream)` and write `int a=getInt(ss), b = getInt(ss);` but `ss >> a >> b` is much more idiomatic.

Comment: You're at the very early stages of writing a parser. Fussing over this syntax is premature. As your code takes shape you'll probably have far bigger fish to fry. Take AlexD's advice and minimize what you're doing, then as you see the shape of the bigger thing you can structure accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you are wondering if there's a way to reduce something like

```
int a, b;
ss >> a >> b;
cout << (a + b) << endl;
```

to something like (*note that this is only pseudo code*)

```
cout << ((ss >> ?) + (ss >> ?)) << endl;
```

There is no way to get around declaring the temporary variables.
Firstly, as others have pointed out, they are needed in case the order of operations is important. Secondly, you need a name on the right-hand-side of the operator.

You can get around specifying the names of the temporaries by hand, but you still need to specify their types. C++ is a statically typed language. The `operator>>` cannot create a variable of a dynamically deduced type for you on the right hand side.

Just as a curiosity, here's my attempt at abstracting the reading of several variables from a stream to only type specifications

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <size_t I=0, typename... T>
std::enable_if_t<I==sizeof...(T)>
collect_impl(std::istream& s, std::tuple<T...>& vars) { }
template <size_t I=0, typename... T>
std::enable_if_t<I!=sizeof...(T)>
collect_impl(std::istream& s, std::tuple<T...>& vars) {
  s >> std::get<I>(vars);
  collect_impl<I+1>(s,vars);
}

template <typename... T>
auto collect(std::istream& s) {
  std::tuple<T...> vars;
  collect_impl(s,vars);
  return vars;
}

void awesome_function(std::tuple<int,int> ii) {
  std::cout << std::get<0>(ii) << ' ' << std::get<1>(ii) << std::endl;
}

void less_awesome_function(int i2, int i1) {
  std::cout << i1 << ' ' << i2 << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  const auto ii = collect<int,int>(std::cin);
  std::cout << std::get<0>(ii) << ' ' << std::get<1>(ii) << std::endl;

  // we can also do
  awesome_function(collect<int,int>(std::cin));

  // with C++17 apply we can even do this
  std::apply(less_awesome_function,collect<int,int>(std::cin));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function

```
int getInt(std::istream& instr)
{
   int n;
   instr >> n;
   return n;
}
```

and then use

```
printf("Result: %d\n", add(getInt(ss), getInt(ss)));
```

**PS**

That approach won't work if order of evaluation of arguments to `add` are important. For example, you can't use:

```
printf("Result: %d\n", subtract(getInt(ss), getInt(ss)));
```

where `subtract` has the usual meaning.

You can, of course, use:

```
int a = getInt(ss);
int b = getInt(ss);
printf("Result: %d\n", add(a, b));
printf("Result: %d\n", subtract(a, b));
```

Comment: @AlexD, you raised a valid point. I'll wait for the downvoters to change their mind :) :)

Comment: Technically speaking, as you already wrote, for `+` the order does not really matter.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
int sum( istream & is ) {
     int n, total = 0;
     while( is >> n ) {
          total += n;
     }
     return total;
}
```

Comment: No unfortunately. I only used sum as my [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My question is only revolving around syntactic sugar, and how to reduce verbosity.

Comment: @AR7  Then it's not clear, to me at least, what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can define an overloaded method like:

```
int add(const std::string & str ) 
{
    std::stringstream ss(str); 
    int a, b,sum; 
    ss >> a; ss >> b;
    return add(a, b);
}
```